# Using conftest python file, but unable to access self.driver methods from test case

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I have created conftest.py file but I am not able to access self.driver methods from my test case.
please let me know what I am missing here, as I am new to python

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

@pytest.fixture()
def setup(request):
    service_obj_chrome = Service("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Selenium 2023/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj_chrome)
    driver.get("https://........")
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

**BaseClass.py**

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    pass
```

**test_case_1.py**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from BaseClass import BaseClass

class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_sample(self, setup):
        self.driver
```

I am looking for all the self.driver methods to be available in my Test.py

Comment: self is a class of test. driver should be pass in the yield (yield driver) and then setup actually would hold the driver otherwise driver is kind of encapulate inside setup fixture

Answer (score 0):

The `pytest.mark.usefixtures` decorator is for those tests that do not directly access to the fixture object. An example would be fixture that cd into a specific directory. In your use case, you want access to the driver, which means you need to yield the driver and do not call `usefixtures`.

##### conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture
def driver(request)
    # code here
    web_driver = ...
    yield web_driver  # Make this object available to the tests
    web_driver.close()
```

##### BaseClass.py

```py
# Do not need usefixtures here
class BaseClass:
    pass
```

##### test_case_1.py

```py
...
class TestOne(BaseClass):
    def test_sample(self, driver):
        # Do something with driver
        driver.get(...)
```